# Tkinter canvas with image is just white

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I have a circular PNG image which is of size `2210×2210` and in my Python application I'm using the `Tkinter` library and `PIL ImageTk & Image` to resize and display the image in a canvas. The code I ended up with is:

```
image=Image.open("/filePath")
image=image.resize((60,60),Image.ANTIALIAS)
powerImage=Tkinter.Canvas(self,width=60,height=60)
powerImage.grid(column=1,row=0)
powerImage.create_image(0,0,image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image),anchor=Tkinter.NW)
```

--Updated Code

```
image=Image.open("/filePath")
image=image.resize((60,60),Image.ANTIALIAS)
powerImage=Tkinter.Canvas(self,width=60,height=60)
powerImage.grid(column=1,row=0)
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
powerImage.create_image(60,60,image=img,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
```

But all I get is a blank white box with the dimensions `60x60`. I don't get any errors and am at the end of my debugging abilities.

I tried changing the position parameter of the `create_image` function to `30x30` and `60x60` just in case the image was just displayed outside of the canvas but I still get just a white box. I also tried using a `gif` version of the image instead off `png` which didn't change anything.

So my question is, why is my image not displaying, and if my image is not displaying why is the canvas white, shouldn't an empty canvas be transparent ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to keep a reference to `ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` like `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)`, then use `photo` in `create_image(..., image=photo, ...)`.  Also, an empty canvas is not transparent.

Comment: I put my updated code like you said, it didn't change, its still exactly the same. And on the empty canvas thing, good to know

Comment: Is your code inside a function?

Comment: its inside the `__init__` function of a custom `Tkinter.Frame class`, thats why I set the canvas parent to `self`

Comment: Then you need to assign `ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` to an instance variable, not local variable, like `self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Could you just maybe explain why that is

Comment: It is because local variable will be destroyed after the function exits and the image which is assigned to the local variable will also be destroyed as there is no variable reference it.

Comment: Related: [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

Comment: save resized image in file and check it in some image viewer - maybe it creates white rectangle.